# Porperly way to share data between Laravel and Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an application with Laravel and Vue. Controller has a method similar to this index

```
   public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $people = Person::all();
        if ($request->ajax()){
            return response()->json($people);
        }
        return view('people.index')->withPeople($people);
    }
```

The problem is: What´it is the right way to get data in front (Vue)?

We can use similar to this code

```
<example-component@prop('people', $people)></example-component>
```

Passing variables in components or we can use Axios.

Comment: Why not use Inertiajs, just courious?

Answer (score 0):

I could do something like the following

```
$people = Person::all();
    if ($request->ajax()){
        return response()->json($people);
    }
```

Using Axios

```
getAll() {      

    return axios.get(`${base_url}/persons`);

}
```

Get all the persons

```
getPersons() {
  return persons
    .getAll()
    .then(response => {
   
      // console.log(this.persons);
  
      this.persons = response.data;
     
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);          
    })
    .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
},
```

In component

```
<example-component>{{persons}}</example-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo php variable inside script tag

In `*.blade.php`

```
<script>
var people = {{ $people }};
</script>
```

In vue script

```js
const people = people; // or const people = window.people || ''
new Vue {
  data() {
    return { people }
  }
}
```

In vue template

```
<example-component@prop('people', people)></example-component>
```